# Two solutions to increase the value of all leaf elements

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, heapsort

I want to increase the value of all the leaf elements. All with index larger than *floor[n/2].

1) Call HEAP-INCREASE-KEY(A,i,key) for each leaf element

2) Increase the key of each leaf element to the new value, then call BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)

Which way would be more efficient and why?

A little extra information, Each call to Max-Heapify costs O(lgn) time, and Build-max-heap makes O(n) such calls. Thus, the running time is O(nlgn). The running time of Heap-Increase-Key is O(lgn).

**HEAP-INCREASE-KEY(A,i,key)**

```
if key<A[i]
  error "new key is smaller than current key.
A[i]
while i>1 and A[Parent(i)]<A[i]
  exchange A[i] with A[Parent(i)]
  i=Parent()
```

**BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)**

```
A.heap-size = A.length
for i = *floor[A.length/2] downto 1
    MAX-HEAPIFY(A,i)
```

if you need to know what max-heapify is

**MAX-HEAPIFY(A,i)**

```
l=Left(i)
r=Right(i)
if l<=A.heap-size and A[l] > A[i]
   largest = l
else largest = i 
if r<=A.heap-size and A[r] > A[largest]
  largest = r
if largest not equal i
   exchange A[i] with A[largest]
   MAX-HEAPIFY (A.largest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **second** one is more efficient.

> 1) Call HEAP-INCREASE-KEY(A,i,key) for each leaf element

The number of leaf elements is `O(n)`. The time for `HEAP-INCREASE-KEY(A,i,key)` is `O(lgn)`. So the time complexity for the first solution is `O(nlgn)`.

> 2) Increase the key of each leaf element to the new value, then call
>   BUILD-MAX-HEAP(A)

To build a heap from scratch only takes linear time. So the time complexity for the second solution is `O(n)`.

> A little extra information, Each call to Max-Heapify costs O(lgn)
>   time, and Build-max-heap makes O(n) such calls. Thus, the running time
>   is O(nlgn).

If this statement was provided in your homework, then the time complexities for both solutions are the same. However, you are able to build a max heap in [linear time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) rather than `O(nlgn)` time.

Comment: That statement was provided in the book.

Comment: So if they all have an index larger than *floor[n/2], that doesn't affect anything?

Comment: @GiBiT09 I think that condition holds for any leaf elements whatsoever.

Comment: @GiBiT09 No problem. Let me know what your professor thinks later :)

Comment: @GiBiT09 By the way, it would be better to add language tags so that your question could get considerably more attention.